# Accessor method is defined but does not work

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

I have this code:

```
class A
  attr_accessor :count

  def initialize
    @count = 0
  end

  def increase_count
    count += 1
  end
end

A.new.increase_count
```

It complains:

```
in `increase_count': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

If I change the `increase_count` definition to:

```
class A
  def increase_count
    @count += 1
  end
end
```

then it does not complain. May be I am missing something, or it is just a weird behaviour of Ruby.

Comment: Why do you want to access an instance variable within the class via an accessor method? The purpose of defining and using an accessor method is to access it from outside of the context of the instance. You are defeating that purpose.

Comment: @sawa: the purpose of accessors is to facilitate access to the variable. Internal usage is perfectly fine. Recommended even.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Why do you need access to a variable to be facilitated when there is already a straightforward `@foo` notation to access it? My understanding is that, defining setter method is an extra step (even if the `attr_...` class method is used), and that design was intended to (mildly) discourage access to instance variables from outside of the instance, following the principles of OOP.

Comment: Guys, this is a simple example mentioned here. But in real scenario, i have one public method, small private methods are being called from inside that public method and all attr_accessors are declared as private in order to avoid sending them as parameters to private methods.

Comment: @Ahmadhamza That is wrong. An attr setter method in the form `foo=` is never private. As Aleksei Matiushkin's answer correctly says, those setter methods are even something that can be called "super-public"; they never **prohibit** an explicit receiver, but they actually **require** one.

Comment: if you declare the attr_accessor as a private, then it complains `private method  'count=' called for #<A:0x00007f85da21e320 @count=[]> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @sawa you must be kidding. Try non-sugared private declaration `private def foo=(value); @foo = value; end` and see you may perfectly make it private.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin You are right in the sense that the method would be listed under private methods. But there is actually no way to call (use) it as a private method, as you as well as I have already mentioned.

Comment: @sawa Ah, got it, indeed. Honestly, there is a way: `Object#send` :)

Comment: I did not understand this part `But there is actually no way to call (use) it as a private method,` ?

Comment: @Ahmadhamza there is actually no way to call (use) it as a private method because **it requires an explicit receiver** which contradicts with it’s private state (you cannot call private methods with an explicit receiver.)

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin (Replying to your comment mentioning `Object#send`.) There is a way **to call it** (such as the way you showed, which applies to all other private methods as well), of course. I wrote there is no way **to call it as a private method**.

Comment: @sawa: "Why do you need access to a variable to be facilitated" - shielding client code from changes. Today it's a simple accessor, but tomorrow it adds memoization and cache write-through. Not to mention that it's one char less to type. In fact, off the top of my head, I can't name a single reason _not_ to use accessors always.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Your argument sounds like the `@foo` notation should be dispensed with from Ruby syntax.

Comment: @sawa I think the use of `@foo` depends mostly on the situation. I like the use of `attr_accessor` because in most cases it helps in not passing attr_accessor variables to the method as they are directly accessible inside the method which is a nice thing.

Comment: @sawa there's no need for `send` – private setters can be called with an explicit receiver of `self`, i.e. `self.foo = ...` is allowed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`A#count=` requires an explicit receiver as all `foo=` methods. Otherwise, the local variable `count` is being created and hoisted, making `count + 1` using *the local not yet initialized variable*.

```
class A
  attr_accessor :count
  def initialize
    @count = 0
  end

  def increase_count
  # ⇓⇓⇓⇓⇓ THIS 
    self.count += 1
  end
end

puts A.new.increase_count   
#⇒ 1
```

*Sidenote:*

`attr_accessor :count` is nothing but a syntactic sugar for:

```
def count
  @count
end

def count=(value)
  @count = value
end
```

Comment: But then it is not the case if the count has been declared other than integer like array, hash etc. For example, `payload` does not complain at all.

Comment: i guess it also better to use setters in `initialize` for the sake of commonality

Comment: @Ahmadhamza You never call `A#payload=`.

Comment: `A#count= requires an explicit receiver as all foo= methods`. Can you please explain this a bit more?

Comment: @Ahmadhamza: if you're doing `count = 1`, do you call the setter? Or do you create a local variable? How to tell these two apart? That's why you have to do `self.count = 1` to refer to the setter

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Ok then why does this does not happen if i declare `count` as an array or hash?

Comment: @Ahmadhamza, it does happen, if you assign to it. `documents += [...]`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev if i declare documents as an array in initialize then it obviously `documents << ..` should be the case. and this does not complain at all.

Comment: `documents <<` calls `documents.class#<<` method. The receiver is required _only_ within `#var=` method. `attr_accessor :foo` is a syntactic sugar for `def foo=(val); @foo = val; end`.

Comment: Got you!! Thanks for the great explanation.

Comment: " is a syntactic sugar for" - it adds a reader too. Did you mean `attr_writer`? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev yeah, “the margins here are too tiny to fit in” (© Fermat)

Comment: `attr_accessor` is not syntactic sugar, it is simply a boring old normal method of `Module`, like any other method.

Comment: Define syntactic sugar.